Pip: Invalid requirement
I'm trying to install a custom package for my project using pip install. The project is using setuptools to create a .whl file.
When trying to install pip like below command, I'm getting error: Invalid requirement.
pip install target/custom_utils-2.0.0_SNAPSHOT-py3-none-any.whl
Error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'custom_utils==2.0.0_SNAPSHOT': Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
    custom_utils==2.0.0_SNAPSHOT
                ~~~~~~~^

This version is violating PEP 440, but setuptool==65.5.1 was still able to handle this. The strange part is, this was working till yesterday. I'm not sure if something changed during night.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/ 2.0.0_SNAPSHOT doesn't look like a valid name. Also maybe pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel.

Possibly a pip issue. There's a recent release that removes support for non-standard version specifiers. Try pinning pip to pip<24.
See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2024-05-06

Remove support for legacy versions and dependency specifiers.
Packages with non standard-compliant versions or dependency specifiers are now ignored by the resolver. Already installed packages with non standard-compliant versions or dependency specifiers must be uninstalled before upgrading them

If you control the version schema of custom_utils, then you can swap the _ for a +, and pip will be more permissive of what comes after the plus. For example: custom_utils==2.0.0+SNAPSHOT would be permitted. Specifically, the bit after the plus is allowed to contain any ASCII letters [a-zA-Z], and digits [0-9] or a period ., and it must not start or end with a period. eg. 2.0.0+SNAPSNOT. would not be allowed, but 2.0.0+SNAP.SHOT would. See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#local-version-identifiers for more details.

Right, that's the pip issue, recent release removes support for non-standard version specifiers. Thanks

This version violates PEP 440, setuptool==65.5.1 was still able to handle this. But in setuptool==66.0.0 this is the change:
v66.0.0 15 Jan 2023
Breaking Changes
#2497: Support for PEP 440 non-conforming versions has been removed. Environments containing packages with non-conforming versions may fail or the packages may not be recognized.
Source - setuptools documentation
The only thing I can advise is to use setuptools version < 66.0.0
